# configure warden rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I started my rails app and suddenly got the following error

```
/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/devise-2.1.2/lib/devise.rb:406:in `configure_warden!': undefined method `failure_app=' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

devise.rb line 406 has:

```
warden_config.failure_app   = Devise::Delegator.new
```

I cannot figure out the problem, how do i go about this?

Comment: can you tell me when exactly you are getting this error?

Comment: When i run rails s to start my application in development mode

Comment: Are you configuring any thing using warden?

Comment: The only thing using warden is Devise, there is nothing else